# What kind of date format is this

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a received a server log which has entries for each row with date something like this below.

23:18.6

23:23.6

I want to convert these dates in DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS format in excel, but when I do this I get value like 00/01/1900 00:23:19

Please can you some let me know what kind of format is this date/time entries.

Comment: These values clearly do not contain enough information to allow you to resolve all the way to DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS

Comment: Do you know, what does each number in log date mean?

Comment: Maybe you nead to use creation/modification time or date contained in the name of the log files to fillup missed date fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like time information with fractional seconds. Something like "[Minutes]:[Seconds].[Fraction]". So Excel is not completely wrong about using it this way when you convert this to date-format.

But are you sure these are timestamps (like a point-in-time) or not rather durations? The output looks much more like duration of operations. In this case, something like elapsed time would be more appropriate.

So you either need to get the date-part from somewhere else (as already suggested in the comments) or showing them as datetime is wrong to begin with.

Comment: I just figured it out that excel when opening a csv file was creating default format of mm:ss.0. Not sure why it was choosing that format and I may have saved the csv file after it had done formatting and thus corrupting raw data in csv file. Got new files and found this behaviour. Thanks everyone for you quick responses. I am using excel 2003 and not sure is it the behaviour of this excel version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the format of the data you have been given.

Find out, from the data's supplier, what the various fields are.